# Silently update url without triggering route in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I need to update the hash of the url, without actually triggering the vue-router to go to that route. Something in the likes of:

```
router.replace('my/new/path', {silent:true})
```

This would update the url to `.../#/my/new/path`, but the router itself would not route to that path.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: what happen when you used this code ?

Comment: Could this be the xy problem..?

Comment: @C2486 this code is just an example of what would be an elegant solution. Unfortunately the second argument in the replace funtion should be an `onComplete` callback.

Comment: @Rainb, might be. I need to load certain pages of our old application sandboxed in an iframe within our new application. When navigating within this iframe, the url hash in the top window should be updated, just so the history will work properly. As the navigation is already done within the iframe, the route itself should not be updated. Once the user actually navigates with the address bar or by using back/forward, the component with iframe should be updated with the correct url. I know, some red flags there, but I need to use the iframe to be able to sandbox the old application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Vue router is either on or off, so you cannot "make it not detect certain urls". That said, Vue does re-use components if it doesn't need to destroy them and allows you to alias urls. This allows you to have the urls from your iframe application as aliases in your route, and keep the same component alive during that time, preventing your iframe from getting reloaded.

```
// router.js
import Comp1 from "./components/Comp1";
import Comp2 from "./components/Comp2";

export default [
  {
    path: "/route1",
    component: Comp1,
    alias: ["/route2", "/route3", "/route4"]
  },
  {
    path: "/otherroute",
    component: Comp2
  }
];
```

```
// main.js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import routes from "./router";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

In this example, `route1`, `route2`, `route3` and `route4` will all be treated as if `route1` has to be loaded, causing your component `Comp1` to stay alive.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: I do not understand how this answers the question. There is no code for the update of the parent window url if the url inside the iframe changes. There is no code for the update of the iframes router if the parent windows url changes.

Comment: @jansolo The behaviour OP wanted was: (1) the url of the parent changes, (2) vue router should not update the view. The solution here is to use an alias so Vue router treats multiple urls as the same route. This question is not about how to update a child iframe with that information, but rather how to avoid reloading that iframe with every route change.

Answer (score 59):

**Without reloading** the page or refreshing the DOM, [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) can do the job.

For example: add this method in your component or elsewhere to do that:

```js
addHashToLocation(params) {
  history.pushState(
    {},
    null,
    this.$route.path + '#' + encodeURIComponent(params)
  )
}
```

Then anywhere in your component you can call `addHashToLocation('/my/new/path')` to push query params to the `window.history` stack.

To add query parameters to current location **without pushing a new history** entry, use [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) instead.

Should work with Vue 2.6.10 and Nuxt 2.8.1.
 
**Be careful with this method**, as [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) does not know that the URL has changed.

Comment: To use this approach with a dynamic URL, you can use the `resolve()` method: 

`const { href } = this.$router.resolve(route); window.history.pushState({}, null, href);`

Comment: Safari throws an Exception if the query is changed multiple times quickly (on scroll for example)

> SecurityError: Attempt to use history.pushState() more than 100 times per 30 seconds

Answer (score 6):

if what you are trying to do is update the url to show the page state (perhaps something like `?search=something`) then you can do a trick like this.  the key idea is using a toggle `this.respondToRouteChanges` to ignore changes when the url is updated by your code.

when updating the route (eg. in a vue method in your component)

```js
          this.respondToRouteChanges = false;
          this.$router.replace({query: { search: this.search })
              .finally(() => {
                this.respondToRouteChanges = true;
              });
```

and in the component code that would normally watch/handle changes to the route

```
    setSearch() {
      if (!this.respondToRouteChanges){
        // console.log('ignoring since route changes ignored')
        return;
      }
      if (this.search !== this.querySearch)
        this.search = this.querySearch;
    },
```

```
  watch: {
     // watch for changes in the url
    'querySearch': 'setSearch',
```

note that `respondToRouteChanges` is just a boolean defined as `data()` in the component

```
  data() {
    return {
      respondToRouteChanges: true,
      ...
```

`querySearch` is just a computed value which returns the route

```
    querySearch() {
      return this.$route.query.search || '';
    },
```

Comment: `this.$router.replace({query: { search: this.search })` is not triggering a redirect anyway ... seems only a change in the URL path is.

Comment: @foobored - there are no redirects, this is about invocations of vue-router. 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-replace-location-oncomplete-onabort

Comment: you are right - thanks for pointing that out. This should be the accepted answer. Maybe replace "in the component code that would normally watch/handle changes route"  to be less generic and more a router guard example like  "in router.beforeEach / component.beforeRouteUpdate"

Comment: it could certainly be a router guard, however, since this is overriding a default behaviour, i think it is probably safer to err on adding it to a specific component (principle of least surprise).  if you need to do it for many components, then there would be a stronger argument for putting it in the router.

Comment: also, i'm not sure you want a component to control some 'respondToRouteChanges' flag in the router - that seems like it could be a bit messy in terms of state/responsibility.

Answer (score -1):

I found how to `Silently update url`, but route anyway is triggered (but this maybe is not a problem - dependents on situation).

In my case user may create a profile, for example via URL `http://localhost:8080/#/user/create/`, provide some profile info and once "Save" is clicked user is redirected to his/her created profile with URL for example `http://localhost:8080/#/FaFYhTW9gShk/`, where the user may continue editing the profile form.

How do I do that?

1. `user/create/` page (ProfileCreate) and `FaFYhTW9gShk/` page (ProfileDetails) use the same `ProfileUser` component.

```
// router.js
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/user/create',
        component: Profile,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'ProfileCreate',
                component: ProfileUser
            }
        ]
    }
    { path: '/:profileUrl',
        component: Profile,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'ProfileDetails',
                component: ProfileUser
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

2. In `router.beforeEach` I check whether I need to load data from the back end, or I need simply to change URL?

```
// router.js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!('isProfileLoaded' in to.params)) {
        // load profile from backend and update Vuex
    }

  next()
})
```

3. When "Save" button is clicked, in `action` I send data to backend + call `router.push`

```
// action.js
import router from '@/router'

// Here I send data to backend
// Some code

// Update-URL-Trick
router.push({
    name: 'ProfileDetails',
    params: { profileUrl: profileUrl isProfileLoaded: true }
})
```

As far as `isProfileLoaded` is provided, Vue re-uses profile's data from Vuex + router `silently` updates URL re-using the same `ProfileUser` component.